# a problem about all goroutines are asleep, a demo of observer pattern

Tags: go, design-patterns, deadlock

the demo is over here, I was tring to use channel to achieve observer pattern, but a fatal error was encountered.
If I use a simple channel in the test, everyting is going well.

Maybe the observer pattern in go shouldn`t like this.

I would appreicate if anybody can help, thank you so much~~~

```
package observer

import "reflect"

type ISubject interface {
    Register(observer IObserver) error
    CancelRegister(observer IObserver) error
    Publish() error
}

type Subject struct {
    RegisterChannels []chan string `json:"registerChannels"`
}

func (s *Subject) Register(observer Observer) error {
    observer.ListenChannel = make(chan string)
    s.RegisterChannels = append(s.RegisterChannels, observer.ListenChannel)
    return nil
}

func (s *Subject) CancelRegister(observer Observer) error {
    for index, val := range s.RegisterChannels {
        if reflect.DeepEqual(val, observer.ListenChannel) {
            s.RegisterChannels = append(s.RegisterChannels[:index], s.RegisterChannels[index+1:]...)
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func (s *Subject) Publish(msg string) error {
    for i := 0; i < len(s.RegisterChannels); i++ {
        s.RegisterChannels[i] <- msg
    }
    return nil
}
```

```
package observer

import "fmt"

type IObserver interface {
    Subscribe()
}

type Observer struct {
    ListenChannel chan string `json:"listenChannel"`
}

func (observer Observer) Subscribe() {
    msg := <-observer.ListenChannel
    fmt.Println(msg)
}
```

```
func Test_Sub(t *testing.T) {
    s1 := Subject{}
    o1 := Observer{}
    err := s1.Register(o1)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    go func() {
        o1.Subscribe()
        fmt.Println(1)
    }()
    fmt.Println(2)
    err = s1.Publish("hahaha")
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: Receiving from a nil channel blocks forever. After `s1.Register`, `o1.ListenChannel` is still nil, because you passed `o1` as value. Pass a `*o1` and change the `Register` function to accept a pointer. You cannot JSON-marshal channels. You should not deep-compare channels. Those are probably not the only errors.

Comment: thank u so much firstly.
I corrected as u said. Pass a *o1.But still deadlock. Is there any demo about observer pattern using go?

Answer (score 0):

You must pass observer object by reference (not by value) or you should make the observer ListenChannel in outside of Register (in Test_Sub func in your test).

By Reference like as:

```
func (s *Subject) Register(observer Observer) error {
    s.RegisterChannels = append(s.RegisterChannels, observer.ListenChannel)
    return nil
}

func Test_Sub(t *testing.T) {
    s1 := Subject{}
    o1 := Observer{}
    err := s1.Register(&o1)
    ...
}
```

or makeing in outside of Register func like as:

```
func (s *Subject) Register(observer Observer) error {
    s.RegisterChannels = append(s.RegisterChannels, observer.ListenChannel)
    return nil

}

func Test_Sub(t *testing.T) {
    s1 := Subject{}
    o1 := Observer{}
    o1.ListenChannel = make(chan string)
    err := s1.Register(o1)
    ...
}
```

Also in your Publish func, I think that better write to the channel with a go routine,
because if a observer couldn't read its channel It will lock all other observer in a subscription

```
func (s *Subject) Publish(msg string) error {
  for i := 0; i < len(s.RegisterChannels); i++ {
    go func(i int) { s.RegisterChannels[i] <- msg }(i)
  }
  return nil
}
```

Comment: go func(i int) { s.RegisterChannels[i] <- msg }(i) ，the key point，thank u so much

Comment: even it's better to use a sync.RWMutex for locking RegisterChannels

Comment: sorry I don`t have enough reputation to vote